# Android Fragment onCreateAnimator enter always true

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-animation, objectanimator, fragment-transitions

I am facing this problem on htc desire 4.0.3.  The animation is always enter, even when fragment is exiting....the problem doesnt exist on 4.4 or 5.0

```
 public Animator onCreateAnimator(int transit, boolean enter, int nextAnim) {
    Animator anim;
    if (enter) {
          Log.d("Animation", "enter");
        anim = ENTER_RIGHT_ANIMATOR;
    } else {
         Log.d("Animation", "exit");
       anim = EXIT_RIGHT_ANIMATOR;
   }
    return anim;

}
```

Comment: Same problem here, also in Android 4.1.2 and 4.2.2 but not in Android  4.4 or 5.0